# Moving from Github to a local TFS server, keeping Github as a backup plan

Tags: github, tfs

We're a small, new development team developing in c# using Visual Studio 2015. We're currently using (actually, not really using) Github for version control, Planbox for agile planning, and a not-properly-set-up-yet instance of Jenkins. We recently added a few developers to our team, and will soon move from individual projects to doing team projects, so we are considering moving all this to a local instance of Microsoft Team Foundation Server.

We'd like to keep our existing and any new projects on Github, mostly as a backup plan, and would like to import them into the new TFS Server, set up with a Git repo. Is there a good way of keeping the Github repos in sync with the TFS repos, without much manual intervention?

Comment: Have you tried Daniel's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a build with a CI trigger that adds GitHub as a remote and pushes to it.